# Optimize pendulum animation (javascript)

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, svg, plotly

TL;DR: I wrote plotly-based javascript simulation of mathematical pendulum. It works very slow. I'm looking for ideas on how to optimize it. Currently trying "bare" d3.js and struggling from the problem of coordinate transformation between SVG's coordinates and my own logical coordinates.

---

I'm writing web-textbook on ordinary differential equations and want to include interactive simulation and visualization of mathematical pendulum. Visualization should contain pendulum itself, its potential energy graph and full energy contour plot. Then user can choose the initial condition by clicking on energy contour plot, then animation should begin showing how the point moves in the phase space.

I wrote an example of such simulation:

https://jsfiddle.net/ischurov/p1krqnt6/

It's plotly-based. I create three axes and put there necessary graphs. The point that represent current state of the system is also a graph in plotly (i.e. scatter plot with the only one point).

Animation works as follows: I get current coordinates of the point in the phase space, calculate the new position of this point after some time, then update my graph according to this new position. The corresponding code:

```
var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');

function updateState(phi, v) {
        var update = {x: [[phi], [phi], [0, Math.sin(phi)]], y: [[v],
            [PotentialEnergy(phi)], [0, -Math.cos(phi)]]};
        Plotly.restyle(div, update, [phaseDotIndex, 3, 4]);
}

myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(data){
    if(data.points[0].data.type == 'contour'){
        updateState(data.points[0].x, data.points[0].y);
    }
});

var animate = null;
$('.animate_button').click(function(){
    var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    if(animate === null) {
        var phi = div.data[phaseDotIndex].x[0],
            v = div.data[phaseDotIndex].y[0], 
            E = FullEnergy(phi, v);
        animate = setInterval(function() {
            var phi = div.data[phaseDotIndex].x[0],
                v = div.data[phaseDotIndex].y[0],
                step = 0.1, newphi, newv, update;

            newphi = phi + v * step;
            newv = v + step * Force(phi);

            /* skip some tweaks here */

            updateState(phi, v);
        }, 
        100)
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(animate);
        animate = null;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

This code works almost as expected, but really slow and not smooth — at least, under Firefox (If I decrease update interval it works even worse).

I'm looking for ways to optimize this.

I believe that performance problems are due to plotly's update process: in order to move one point it have to recalculate the whole picture and it is slow. So I'm looking for ways to do it in different way.

Are there any ideas?

I'm looked for some direct d3.js approach which can be faster. I see the following steps here:

1. Draw a graph of potential energy and contour plot of full energy.
2. Draw the pendulum itself.
3. Put small circles on the graphs of potential energy and contour plot.
4. Make 'onclick' event handler to allow user to choose the initial state.
5. Run animation loop by updating the position of the circles and the pendulum according to current state.

To proceed with step 1, I can use third-party d3.js libraries like [conrec](https://github.com/jasondavies/conrec.js) for contour plots and/or excellent [maurizzzio's function plot](http://maurizzzio.github.io/function-plot/) or even plotly itself (but I'm not going to use plotly to update the graph). Step 2 seem to be doable, but I didn't try it yet. The most difficult for now are steps 3 and 4 as I don't understand how to transform SVG coordinates into my graph's coordinates (that are plotted with some library) and vice-versa.

Or maybe there are more simple ways to do it?

Comment: One way to improve animations is to use `requestAnimationFrame`; this allows the browser to optimize when your animation function gets called.

Comment: Although very interesting work, this question is a little too broad for stackoverflow.  Your concern with `how to transform SVG coordinates into my graph's coordinates` is solved by using d3s [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) objects.  d3 has a steep learning curve, but if you are serious about creating the best web-based visualizations possible; IMHO it's the tool for the job.  So, I'd take a step back, study some smaller d3 examples, wrap your head around it and then attempt this more complicated simulation.

Comment: @mark, I can partially agree. Actually, I thought about asking question like "how to transform coordinates from SVG-based plotting library X and SVG itself", but I'm not sure which library to use, so I dediced to give more context and state more broad question (maybe, too broad). Thanks for scale objects: unfortunately, I need to know some information from the plotting library to initialize scale object properly, and I don't know how to get this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of [function plot](http://maurizzzio.github.io/function-plot/) which is built on top of d3, luckily d3 has methods to perform mappings in [d3-scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) so assuming that you have a canvas of `width x height` dimensions which should be mapped linearly to the rectangle `[xMin, yMin] x [xMax, yMax]` in 2D euclidean space you'd need to create two linear scales

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([xMin, xMax])
  .range([0, width])

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([yMin, yMax])
  .range([height, 0])
```

Note that in SVG the y axis is flipped and because of that the `yScale` range's flipped too, then any 2D euclidean point is transformed to SVG coordinates as follows

```
var xCanvas = xScale(point.x)
var yCanvas = yScale(point.y)
```

The inverse transformation is given by

```
var xLogical = xScale.invert(point.x)
var xLogical = yScale.invert(point.y)
```

A possible solution I wrote to your problem using the above is

```js
var instance = functionPlot({
  target: '#demo',
  disableZoom: true,
  data: [{
    fn: 'sin(10*(-cos(x) + y^2/2-1))',
    fnType: 'implicit'
  }]
})
var xScale = instance.meta.xScale
var yScale = instance.meta.yScale
var canvas = instance.canvas

var circle = canvas.append('circle')
  .attr("r", 5)
  .style("fill", "purple")

var start = Date.now()

function animate() {
  
  // move the point along the circle of radius 1
  var t = (Date.now() - start) * 0.003
  var xLogical = Math.cos(t)
  var yLogical = Math.sin(t)
  var xCanvas = xScale(xLogical)
  var yCanvas = yScale(yLogical)
  circle
    .attr('cx', xCanvas)
    .attr('cy', yCanvas)
  
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

animate()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maurizzzio.github.io/function-plot/js/function-plot.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

[Issue in function plot's GitHub](https://github.com/maurizzzio/function-plot/issues/59)

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this isn't exactly what you want but it does demonstrate that your code can be compact and still do what you require.

The following is some code that demonstrates some maths to animate a pendulum, extracted from one of my javascript widgets but the math logic should still be usable in your own project.

Create an image object - pendulumSet, a nice round ball will do.

```
// variables set for the pendulum

var gravity = -0.0110808; // tuned to -0.110808 as it approximates a 1 second interval
var acceleration = 0.1; //0.1
var velocity = 0.18; //.18
var angle = 8; // 8 (.4 radians = 22.91 degrees)
```

Create a timer with an interval of 0.01 seconds

Put this in the timer:

```
acceleration = gravity * angle;
velocity += acceleration;
angle += velocity;
pendulumSet.rotation = angle +180; // rotation as per a widget engine
```

That's it...

You might have to use something like the following to achieve the rotation in native javascript:

```
pendulumSet.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)"; // change the 90deg
```

This code above will simulate a pendulum in a much more compact fashion.  This is 1/100th of a second, graphic animation and mathematical calculation so it will take some cpu, that is unavoidable. Nevertheless, the code is compact and the impact is minimal. Depending upon the engine interpreting the code, the cpu usage will be approx. 20-25% of a 2.5ghz core2duo from 2009, easily handled by more modern, faster cpus. Running similar code in Firefox may be noticeably slower as Firefox, in my experience, seems to perform similar animations less efficiently. You just have to try it and see.

The code is taken from this example javascript widget:
[A steampunk clock for the desktop](https://yereverluvinuncleber.deviantart.com/art/Steampunk-Clock-Calendar-MKII-2-8-277413550)

So you can see the exact same code in operation.

[image]